# Google Calendar Url feed incorrect for recurring events

Tags: php, xml

I am using the following code to parse XML data from a Google Calendar feed:

```
    require_once('coreylib/coreylib.php');

    $calendar = variable_get('calendar_id_setting');

    $now = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('now'));
    $next_week = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+7 days'));
    $api = new clApi('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' . $calendar .'/public/full?singleevents=true&amp;min-start=' . $now . '&amp;max-start=' .$next_week);

    if ($feed = $api->parse()) {

        foreach($feed->get('entry') as $entry) {

                  error_log($title . ' ' . strtotime($entry->get('when@startTime')));
```

The problem is in the error log my first result is a unique event with correct title and time, but the following 25 results all have the same title and have a start time in 2026(?!).

All but one of the events are recurring events. I thought setting 'singleevents=true' on the URL would solve this problem but apparently not! What is the correct fix here?

Comment: Why the HTML entity escaping (`&amp;`) in the URL?

Comment: It was something I added after I read up on it. I still had the same problems before though regardless. Take it out then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare your URL with the one in the [Calendar API v2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingDateRange). You're providing parameters `min-start` and `max-start`, in a format of `'Y/m/d'`. The documentation shows an example with parameters of

```
start-min=2006-03-16T00:00:00&start-max=2006-03-24T23:59:59
```

Note the use of `start-min` and `start-max`, and a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Given the [parameter reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference#Parameters) I suspect you could get away with just `yyyy-MM-dd`, but you should follow that format rather than using slashes and single-digit versions.

Of course that doesn't quite explain the results you're getting in 2026, but using the right parameters would be a good starting point.

Additionally, you may wish to consider using the [v3 API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) and possibly the [PHP (beta) client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

(Note: although I work for Google and used to use the client API myself, this answer is provided purely in a personal capacity.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, note in PHP time it is H:m:s, still I've sorted that out now. I wasn't sure what version I was using, only that I used CoreyLib to parse the XML data. How do I change this?

Comment: @RickDonohoe: Well if you look in the v3 docs, you'll see that the v3 URLs start with this: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3

Comment: Would I use 
$api = new clApi('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar .'/events?singleevents=true'); ??

Comment: That automated it into a link and added a semi colon, but you get the idea.

Comment: @RickDonohoe: I don't know - I haven't used the v3 API and I'm not a PHP developer. I suggest you look at the documentation for the v3 client library.